# How do you define/declare a swift method for an objc protocol that has a reference return type?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I created an objc protocol:

```
@protocol CGEventTapHandler
  - (CGEventRef)onCGEvent:(CGEventTapProxy)proxy type:(CGEventType)type event:(CGEventRef)event;
@end
```

Then in my swift class I get the signature:

```
func onCGEvent(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent!) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>!
```

Now it gets confusing. I get a number of errors.

First error is:

```
...: Protocol requires function 'onCGEvent(_:type:event:)' with type '(CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent!) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>!'

...: Candidate is not '@objc', but protocol requires it
```

So I add '@objc' to the signature then I get:

```
...: Method cannot be marked @objc because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

Edited per request:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, CGEventTapHandler {
  func onCGEvent(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent!) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>! {
  }
}
```

Comment: Everything has been shown... the "candidate" is defined as `class ViewController: NSViewController, CGEventTapHandler` -- the protocol method sig is above.

Comment: This is no longer relevant with the availability of Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely certain where your error lies, so here is a tutorial that works.
Start with a fresh, new, **Swift** project targeted to **OS X**.

**Create an Objective-C Protocol**

File name: *CGEventTapHandler.h*. When prompted to create the Bridging-Header, approve.

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
@protocol CGEventTapHandler
- (CGEventRef)onCGEvent:(CGEventTapProxy)proxy type:(CGEventType)type event:(CGEventRef)event;
@end
```

**Register Protocol**

File name: *...-Bridging-Header*

```
#import "CGEventTapHandler.h"
```

**Adopt Protocol**

In you client class, adopt `CGEventTapHandler`:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController, CGEventTapHandler {
    func onCGEvent(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent!) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>! {
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

*Compiled, linked, built and ran*. No warnings, no errors.